# Java - Is there a way a client and a server can connect via IPv4 without port forwarding?

Tags: java, sockets

So I'm trying to connect two clients in a Java application, but in a way that one client acts as a server and other client acts as a ... client. I managed to connect them locally which works perfect, but I've been researching whether I can connect a client to a server that are not on a same network (via IPv4 or IPv6). I have read that I should do port forwarding on my router server-side. I know how to port forward, but shouldn't it be possible to do without port forwarding? If I understand correctly, only server-side should be port forwarded and the server can respond to the client without the need for the client to port forward their router? So if I'm correct, another solution would be a 'global' third party server(that is port forwarded) that would connect two clients by receiving and passing information from one client to another?

I'm just learning here, so I'm sorry if this has already been answered here but I haven't found answers to all of this in one place and I'm trying to come to a conclusion.

Comment: If your ADSL-router (and/or your Internet Service Provider) does Network Addsess Translation then you have to do port forwarding. Not programming question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> shouldn't it be possible to do without port forwarding

Yes, you can make a connection between two machines without [port-forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding).

## Example: Web servers

Take for example, web servers. By default a web server sits there listening on [port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking)) 80, with 80 being the [port assigned by convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking)#Common_port_numbers) for [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol).

The web client (browser or such) sends a request by trying to connect on port 80. If there are no obstacles in the way, then the connection proceeds.

### Restricted port access

However, there may be an obstacle.

One common obstacle: [Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix)-oriented operating systems (BSD, macOS, Solaris, Linux, AIX, etc.) by convention restrict access to ports numbered under 1,024 for security reasons. The operating system blocks any incoming connections on port 80. With that security blockage in place, the web request never reaches the server.

#### Port-forwarding with a packet-filter tool

One way to get past this restriction is to have the web server listen on an unrestricted port, a port numbered above 1,024, up to the 64K limit, such as 8080. Then configure the [packet filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)#First_generation:_packet_filters) tool on the server machine’s OS to do port-forwarding. The incoming request for port 80 is altered to go to port 8080 instead.

A connection is then established between the web server and the web client.

- The client thinks it is talking to the server on port 80.
- The server thinks the client asked for port 8080.

With the packet filter tool in the middle altering packets on-the-fly, both server and client is none the wiser about packets being altered.

You may want to configure your firewall to allow HTTP connections from outside the machine only on 80, including blocking any external requests for 8080. In this case, only packets altered from 80 to 8080 will reach your web server. Common practice is to close as many ports as possible on a server.

FYI: For encrypted HTTP ([HTTPS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS)), the conventional port is 443 rather than 80.

## Not a programming issue

Notice that there is **no programming issue here**. As the programmer, your client software should attempt to connect on the port number as documented for the server in which you are interested. On the server-side machine, or server-side router, port-forwarding will be configured as needed. Your client programming does not care about, or even know about, any port-forwarding that may or may not be in place. Port-forwarding is a [network-admin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_administrator) issue, and should be transparent to the programmer.

## See sister sites for networking issues

As a network-admin issue, look to the sister sites such as [*Server Fault*](https://serverfault.com/) and [*Network Engineering*](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) rather than *Stack Overflow*.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer! I've tried using port 80 but I immediately brushed that idea off because I got restricted from using it (I'm on Ubuntu). Seems like this actually is one of the better solutions I'll use and alter port 80 to port 8080. Thanks :-).

Comment: @Glavatar By the way, packet-filter tools have evolved with older ones supplanted by newer ones. Sometimes they co-exist installed together on an OS. You will likely want to focus on the newer tools when investing your time to learn. For example, [my Question on macOS El Capitan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/230300/17907).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can access a computer from outside the network and connect to a server
You must download the (ngrok) tool on the device that contains the server and run the tool
The client will contact the server without the need to forward the ports

[ngrok](https://dashboard.ngrok.com/)

Explain the use of the tool on the site with a download link

Comment: I worked a lot of chat and file transfer programs in Java for Windows. You can share your code if you encounter problems

Comment: I will give ngrok a shot, thank you for recommending it :-)